# Gravitational Attraction Central Force

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I understand that a central force is one always pointing to the same fixed point, in the same direction (parallel) as the position vector $\mathbf r$, and whose magnitude only varies depending on the magnitude of $\mathbf r$ (the distance to the fixed point).

So am I correct in assuming that gravitational attraction between a planet orbiting the Sun is a central force. I was unsure because the force acts towards the centre of the system but I thought it was perpendicular to the position vector of the planet.

Also, say if you have a ball that you throw vertically up in the air, is gravity a central force in this case ? And the same for a projectile ?

Comment: What is a one-body system , compared with a 2-body system? And second, what are the length scales involved, the distances of the movement compared to the distance to the gravity center? Or if you want, what is the, geometric, difference between a cannon shot and an ICBM?